# C create string from contents of file, Sedona roots

Tags: c, file-io, fopen

I'm working in a language called Sedona that can take native C methods. In order to integrate C in sedona, the variable declarations are a bit off.

1. Sedona -> C

   - bool  -> int32_t
   - bool[]    -> uint8_t*
   - byte  -> int32_t
   - byte[]    -> uint8_t*
   - short -> int32_t
   - short[]   -> uint16_t*
   - int   -> int32_t
   - int[] -> int32_t*
   - long  -> int64_t
   - long[]    -> int64_t*
   - float -> float
   - float[]   -> float*
   - double    -> double
   - double[]  -> double*
   - Obj   -> void*
   - Obj[] -> void**
   - Str   -> uint8_t*
   - Str[] -> uint8_t**

My method is trying to open a file, read its contents and return the contents of the file as a string for the other Sedona method to use. I know most of you probably don't know Sedona, but it is either not returning the string correctly, not building it correctly or not creating it correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sedona.h"

Cell lynxspringWeblet_MainWeblet_getFile(SedonaVM* vm, Cell* params){
    Cell result;
    int64_t size;
    uint8_t* fileContents;
    int32_t itter = 0;
    uint8_t* ch;
    uint8_t* file_name = params[0].aval;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); //read mode
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    fileContents = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

    if (fp==NULL){
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ch = "l";
    while ((*ch = fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        fileContents[itter] = *ch;
        itter++;

    }
    result.aval = fileContents;
    fclose(fp);
    return result;
}
```

It's compiling, but the SVM is crashing, and I've narrowed it down to the while loop that has the issues. I don't think I'm building the string correctly. It compiles, so I know there are no glaring errors, but it still doesn't work correctly.

**Can someone tell me**

1) what this is currently doing?

2) Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem lies here:

```
ch = "l";
while ((*ch = fgetc(fp))!=EOF) {
    ....
}
```

You are assigning `ch` to be a pointer to a string literal. And string literals are not modifiable. You immediately attempt to modify the string literal.

I guess that `fgetc` returns an `int32_t`, following your type mappings. In which case you should change `ch` to be of type `int32_t` and write the loop like this:

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp))!=EOF) {
    ....
}
```

On the other hand, perhaps the type mapping needs to happen else where and maybe you are meant to use `int`. But for sure you cannot use `uint8_t` for the reasons that Chris outlines.

Note that I have no knowledge at all of Sedona so expect some of these details to be awry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since `ch` is a `uint8_t *`, the expression `(*ch = fgetc(fp))!=EOF` (your while condition) will always be true.  When you get to the end of file, `fgetc` will return `EOF`, which will be implicitly converted to `255` (in order to store it in `*ch`) and then compared to `EOF`.

You need to keep the value returned by `fgetc` as an `int`, and compare it (as an `int`) with `EOF` *before* converting it to a `uint8_t` to store in the string.  Something like:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    fileContents[itter] = ch;
    itter++:
}
```